# Attempt at proving the first part of the FTC

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

I have only glanced at the proofs for the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, as an exercise I tried to prove it myself. I kindly ask you for some feedback on the solidity, validity, etc. of my attempt.

I use the limit of a sequence rather than the continuous limit since in my analysis class we are mostly using the definition $lim_{x\to a} f(x)=lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n}), (x_{n})\to a$, where $lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n})$ is the same for all sequences $(x_{n})\to a$

Let f:[a,b] $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous (and thus integratable) and
$$F(x):= \int_a^x f(t)dt \quad \space p \in [a,b]$$

$$F'(p)=\lim_{x\to p} \dfrac{F(x)-F(p)}{x-p}=\lim_{x\to p} \dfrac{\int_a^{x} f(t)dt-\int_a^p f(t)dt}{x-p}$$

so we have to look at the limit for a general sequence general $(x_{n})_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \to p$, $x_{n}\in[a,b] \space \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{F(x_{n})-F(p)}{x_{n}-p}=\lim_{n \to\infty} \dfrac{\int_a^{x_{n}} f(t)dt-\int_a^p f(t)dt}{x_{n}-p}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\delta(x_{n},p)\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)} f(t)dt}{x_{n}-p}$$ with $\delta:= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      1 & x_{n}\geq p \\
      -1 & x_{n}< p 
      \end{array} \right/$

If $x_{n}\geq p$: $$\int_a^{x_{n}} f(t)dt-\int_a^p f(t)dt=\int_{p}^{x_{n}}f(t)dt=\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)} f(t)dt=\delta\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)}f(t)dt$$

If $x_n<p$: $$\int_a^{x_{n}} f(t)dt-\int_a^p f(t)dt=-(\int_a^p f(t)dt-\int_a^{x_{n}} f(t)dt)=\delta(\int_{x_{n}}^{p}f(t)dt)=\delta\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)}f(t)dt$$

$min(x_{n},p),max(x_{n},p) \in [a,b]$ so $f$ is continuous in this interval, so according to the mean value theorem $\exists\theta_{n}\in[min(x_{n},p),max(x_{n},p)]$ with $$f(\theta_{n})(max(x_{n},p)-min(x_{n},p))=\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)}f(t)dt$$

This forms a sequence $(\theta_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $\theta_{n}$ is any  $\theta_{n}\in[min(x_{n},p),max(x_{n},p)]$ with $$f(\theta_{n})(max(x_{n},p)-min(x_{n},p))=\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)}f(t)dt$$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\delta\int_{min(x_{n},p)}^{max(x_{n},p)} f(t)dt}{x_{n}-p}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\delta f(\theta_{n})(max(x_{n},p)-min(x_{n},p))}{x_{n}-p}=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\theta_{n})$ since $\delta(max(x_{n},p)-min(x_{n},p))=x_{n}-p$ in all cases

$f$ is continuous in [a,b] and all $\theta_{n} \in [min(x_{n},p),max(x_{n},p)] \subseteq [a,b]$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\theta_{n})= f(\lim_{n\to\infty} \theta_{n})$

$\dfrac{x_{n}+p-|x_{n}-p|}{2}=min(x_{n},p)\leq\theta_{n}\leq max(x_{n},p)=\dfrac{x_{n}+p+|x_{n}-p|}{2}$

$x_{n}$ is a sequence that converges to p so:

for all $\epsilon >0 \space\exists N:|x_{n}-p|<\epsilon \space \forall n\geq N$

$\\ -\epsilon<x_{n}-p<\epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon+2p<x_{n}+p<\epsilon+2p$

$\\\\$
$-\epsilon+p=\dfrac{-\epsilon +2p -\epsilon}{2}\leq\dfrac{x_{n}+p-|x_{n}-p|}{2}\leq\theta_{n}\leq \dfrac{x_{n}+p+|x_{n}-p|}{2}\leq\dfrac{\epsilon +2p +\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon+p$

$-\epsilon<\theta_{n}-p<\epsilon \Rightarrow |\theta_{n}-p|<\epsilon \space \forall n\geq N$

So $F'(p)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}\theta_{n})=f(p)$

Comment: You didn't elaborate on why you think there is an issue with the usual proof. The usual proof(s) are correct and has been reviewed by bajillions of people

Comment: I changed it now, but I just meant to give context as to how I came up with an alternative proof, not that there is a real problem with the usual proof

Comment: How is this an alternative proof? You still use the mean value theorem. I haven't looked at the common proof in many years, so maybe I am missing some minute details, but it looks like you are using the common path, except for replacing the continuous limit with a sequence for no apparent reason. (And of course you are proving only the first FTC, aka the "Differentiation Theorem", not the second FTC, which is the one referred to when one says just "the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus").

Answer (score 0):

Arguably not an answer, but awkward for a comment yet hopefully helpful as feedback. Two algebraic observations will greatly simplify your approach:

1. Re-write
   $$
   \frac{\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\, dt - \int_{a}^{p} f(t)\, dt}{x - p}
   $$
   as
   $$
   \frac{1}{x - p} \int_{p}^{x} f(t)\, dt.
   $$
2. Write $f(p)$ (N.B. not $F'(p)$) as
   $$
   \frac{1}{x - p} \int_{p}^{x} f(p)\, dt.
   $$
   (Right? :)

Now consider the absolute value of the difference, and use monotonicity of the integral, the triangle inequality, and continuity of $f$ at $p$ to show
$$
|F'(p) - f(p)|
= \lim_{x \to p} \biggl|\frac{1}{x - p} \int_{p}^{x} \bigl(f(t) - f(p)\bigr)\, dt\biggr| = 0.
$$